# Save data in datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine

If I have a class and a list (But in my case are about 30 values):

```
class ABC(ndb.model):
   x = ndb.StringProperty()
   y = ndb.StringProperty()
   z = ndb.StringProperty()

var = {'x': 'oi', 'y': 'tim', 'z': 'vivo'}
```

and I want to save those values in the datastore, is there a way gave use a for or while loop when calling the class to save the values without which I need to set one value eg:

```
xabc = ABC(x = var['x'], y = var['y'], z = var['z'])
xabc.put()
```

Answer (score 1):

I see no "list" here as described in your question, so I don't know if I've interpreting your question correctly.

I think you're trying to ask: how do I initialize an `ABC` instance, given a dictionary with a dynamic (but limited) set of key/value pairs?

If I understand what your intent is, then you should be able to do a simple loop over the dictionary's key/value pairs, and use `setattr()` to push those keys into your entity.

```
xabc = ABC()
for key, value in var.iteritems():
    setattr(xabc, key, value)
```

Alternative approach: you can directly use the constructor, feeding in the keyword arguments from the dictionary using `**` to splice in keyword arguments:

```
xabc = ABC(**var)
```

Do you have any limits on what kind of keys will be in your dictionary?  It would be very nice if you knew up front what these are.  Where is the dictionary coming from?

Comment: as dyoo has mentioned you need to ensure that the keys of the dictionary need to be a valid property of the model or if you can unsure, you should ideally wrap it in a try/catch.

Comment: I have a class ABC says that the field names from the database. And I have a dictionary of values (var) which contains several passed by POST values.
But as I have many variables would like to know if there is a more dynamic way to save it, since the name of the values in the dictionary would be the same field names from the database. Ai was thinking of using a loop to repeat it again and add the name to set the name and then call the class to save the database loop repeating itself passed the arguments of the field name in the database and its value.

Comment: In this context then, I would recommend a lot of caution.  I personally would not feel comfortable doing anything too dynamic here, especially if the dictionary is externally sourced.  Some attributes of an entity should be treated as  "privileged", such as `key`.  You don't want external content to just reach in and affect such wide-reaching attributes without any restrictions: that's just asking to be abused.